# Email Notification System in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I was looking to develop an email notification system of sorts where the user could create and edit a variety of email templates and assign them to certain tasks/functions. All these functions are are just scheduled dates for certain reviews. So say a review is scheduled for 2 years from now; the user wants to be able to get an email notification approximately 30 days prior (or another arbitrary time) reminding them to conduct the actual review. Another problem is how to schedule the email to be sent on a specific date without them being in the system so it's triggered on a date and not another event.

The scheduling of reviews is already set up and the creation of the email templates is easy enough but how does one set up an email notification system that can email it's users when not in the system? If anyone could point me in the right direction or could provide me with some advice, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks all.

Comment: What email system are you targeting?

Comment: *how does one set up an email notification system that can email it's users when not in the system?* - Your system should run as a [Windows service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_service) which runs 24/7.

Comment: If the logic could be written in SQL, use MySQL [EventScheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/events-overview.html), otherwise you can create a Windows Service or [schedule it on Task Scheduler](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc748993.aspx) or, put them right in your ASP.NET as [background tasks](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here are  links to get started:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972339.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hello I have done the same I have create the console Application and I am not closing the console application.

the Last line I have write is "Console.ReadLine()"

when you received new email then OnNotificationEvent event will fire.

below is the sample code.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EmailExchange emailExchange = new EmailExchange();
            emailExchange.Domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Domain"];
            emailExchange.EmailID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailID"];
            emailExchange.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];                
            emailExchange.Watch();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }


public class EmailExchange : IDisposable
    {
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string EmailID { get; set; }
        public string Domain { get; set; }            
        public string ExchangeURL
        {
            get { return "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx"; }
        }        
        private StreamingSubscriptionConnection connection = null;
        private ExchangeService service = null;
        public void Watch()
        {
            service = new ExchangeService();
            service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(EmailID, Password, Domain);            
            service.Url = new Uri(ExchangeURL);
            StreamingSubscription streamingsubscription = service.SubscribeToStreamingNotifications(new FolderId[] { WellKnownFolderName.Inbox }, EventType.NewMail);            
            connection = new StreamingSubscriptionConnection(service, 5);
            connection.AddSubscription(streamingsubscription);
            connection.OnNotificationEvent += OnNotificationEvent;
            connection.OnSubscriptionError += OnSubscriptionError;
            connection.OnDisconnect += OnDisconnect;
            connection.Open();
        }

        private void OnDisconnect(object sender, SubscriptionErrorEventArgs args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Disconnected");
            if (!connection.IsOpen)
                connection.Open();
        }

        private void OnSubscriptionError(object sender, SubscriptionErrorEventArgs args)
        {

        }

        private void OnNotificationEvent(object sender, NotificationEventArgs args)
        {
            foreach (var notification in args.Events)
            {
                if (notification.EventType != EventType.NewMail) continue;

                var itemEvent = (ItemEvent)notification;               
                // add you code here
            }
        }



        public void Dispose()
        {
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
```